# How to profile tornado callbacks

Tags: tornado

Is there an easy way to profile and/or trace the order of callbacks being run in Tornado's `IOLoop` and the callback duration?  I know about `IOLoop.set_blocking_log_threshold()` for seeing if something is blocked and taking a long time, but I am more interested in the work being done by the `IOLoop` and what tasks it is running.

I can use python's profiling libraries or run it in a debugger, but was just wondering if there was an easy switch to flip to dump that info to the logger or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing built-in to Tornado for this, but you can use general-purpose profiling tools. Stack-sampling profilers are well-suited for collecting profile data from running services including Tornado. I know that [Plop](https://github.com/bdarnell/plop) works to profile Tornado applications and I think [nylas-perftools](https://github.com/nylas/nylas-perftools) does too.

Comment: Is there exist a non-Intrusive tools to achieve profiling Tornado HTTP server?